# How to Calculate the normalised data of column using population?

Tags: r

[London City number Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhsHK.png)

Population of London city numbers is 100,000. How can I calculate the normalized data using population? I have searched and spent a lot of time to find out any clue but failed. I find ways to normalize data without using population number but did not find any way to normalize the data using population number. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalized data"?

Comment: If you mean normalizing the data, then just google, you will find plenty of results

Comment: There are plenty of ways I can normalise data. I know and tried to find an answer for normalising data but nothing comes out "USING POPULATION". As I am not a statistics student, I think a statistics student/practitioner will find it easy